# Rails 4 - Update Join Table Attributes with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, join

This is a follow-up of my question: [Rails 4 - Access Join Table Value in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921063/rails-4-access-join-table-value-in-views)

Now I know how to retrieve join table attributes and show them in view. But still I can't find the right approach to edit and update the attribute.

Models:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient

  #there is an attribute t.text :amount
end
```

Recipe#Edit:

```
...
<%= simple_form_for @recipe do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :name, input_html: { class: "form-control"} %>
      <%= f.input :description, input_html: { class: "form-control"} %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:ingredient_ids, Ingredient.all, :id, :title, {}, {multiple: true}) %>
      <!-- reserve for recipe_ingredients.amount -->
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", disable_with: 'Submitting...', class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  <% end %>
...
```

As shown above, this is a many-to-many relationship, each recipe may have several ingredients. It works fine and I can choose the right models to associate with (using collection_select). But I have left the work to edit and update join table attributes undone. I have two ideas in my mind:

1. Make another edit page for editing join model attributes
2. Ajax? But not quite familiar with

I know the question seems to be trivial, but many solutions are out-dated(Rails 3). Desperate for a Rails 4 solution.

**Edit**

Intention: I would like to make the creation of Recipe and Ingredient models on their own, which is done. User will see which recipe using the ingredient in Ingredient#show action, which is done also. As to Recipe#show action, there is a slight difference, where user will see which ingredient it is using as well as the amount(join table attribute), which is done in my previous question. The last problem is, I would like to make this attribute editable.

Comment: One solution is to make it 'manual', add an input field for each recipe and in your controller read and set the value. I guess there is a `simple_form and rails`- solution though and are eager to read it.

Comment: is there any source for reference?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into doing nested models combined with the cocoon gem. This will allow you to have a form which updates multiple models at once and it takes care of all the ajax for you. https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon. I used this gem on a system where the user needed to be able to add one or more answers to a trivia question via dynamic form fields. I think it could work for you as well with giving the user the ability to add one or many RecipeIngredient relations for a recipe. You would be able to add selects dynamically to your form via Cocoon containing a select with the Ingredient model records.

Comment: I don't know if nested models will do what I want. In fact, I would like to make the creation of Recipe and Ingredient models on their own, which is done. User will see which recipe using the ingredient in Ingredient#show action, which is done also. As to Recipe#show action, there is a slight difference, where user will see which ingredient it is using as well as the amount(join table attribute), which is done in my previous question. The last problem is, I would like to make this attribute editable. What should be the best approach for this? Many thanks

Comment: Edited the post and added the intention. Thanks for your suggestion. But it seems that the samples are all about a nested create form where user can add association with attributes dynamically. A bit different from what I intend. Trying to work around with cocoon to see if modifiable anyway.